# Is it possible to handle the bind for just one specific property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building an application where the culture is *pt-BR*. In this case decimal places are distinguished by `,` instead of `.`.

This works nicely with every case I have here **but** the [Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_geolocation.asp) got by the browser.

```
public class ClientData
{   
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

In this case I receive a number like `-30.028212` but the Model Binder can't convert it to a `float` because it was expecting `-30,02821`.

I know I can create a custom `ModelBinder` for this and I know I could create a `string` property and convert myself in another one but I want to know if the Framework has a **built in solution for this case**.

I was looking for a solution the kind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739534/defining-the-cultureinfo-of-a-property-using-dataannotation) but the OP already gave up.

Is it possible to handle the conversion of just one property by using a ASP.NET MVC solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to solve this would be to use the property.

```
private string latitude;
public string Latitude
{
    get
    {
        NumberFormatInfo format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
        format.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
        return decimal.Parse(latitude).ToString(format);
    }
    set
    {
        latitude = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about some like this but I'm really searching for a built in solution. I managed to "solve" with a `string` property for ModelBinder and another one I consume with `float` and a `Convert.ToSingle("-31.3", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`